# How to return last used record?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have simple table called ips with 2 field ip and address, which schema is following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ips` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ips_address_unique` (`address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

in table there are some IP inserted

```
INSERT INTO `ips` (`id`, `address`) VALUES (1, '123.123.123.123');
INSERT INTO `ips` (`id`, `address`) VALUES (1, '124.124.124.124');
INSERT INTO `ips` (`id`, `address`) VALUES (1, '125.125.125.125');
```

**How to create query that return** `123.123.123.123` **first time**, `124.124.124.124` **second time**, `125.125.125.125` **third time**, `123.123.123.123` **fourth time and so on...?**

The only one solution that comes to my mind is idea of storing id of last returned IP in memory and then query for ip with id greater than stored. Anyway, I'm going to repeat that query multiple times in a second. It will be inefficient.

Comment: Why?  What are you attempting to solve?

Comment: I have to use different IP as often as possible. MySQL RAND() can return me the same IP in 2 following queries. In this case I need some sort of list and put last used IP at the end of it. I can't hardcode this, because I need to manage IPs and remove them from list when it will be inactive.

Comment: I posted another answer that's MySQL specific. Please look it over http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68169/877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply add a bit column to your table, and update the bit column when assigning an IP.

The table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ips` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  , `used` bit NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ips_address_unique` (`address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Your code would then access the table something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 `ad`, `address`, `used`
FROM `ips`
WHERE `used` = 0;

UPDATE `ips`
SET `used` = 1
WHERE `address` = "the ip address";
```

---

I know next to nothing about MySQL, so the syntax is probably incorrect.

Comment: Your solution is awesome by its simplicity but there is still one drawback. I need to do extra queries to check whether table is not fully filled with "used" records.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for `SEQUENCE`, simple usage:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ip_seq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

and then in `select`:

```
where id = ip_seq.nextval % ip_table_size
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately MySQL hasn't own sequences, whereas Postgresql has. In this case the simplest solution will be switching DBMS.

Comment: Couldn't you add an autoincrementing field and simply run @ProblemFactory's query with that?

Answer (score 1):

## OPTION #1

You could retrieve the last `id` and then retrieve the `address` for that `id`

```
SELECT id INTO @MaxID FROM ips ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT address FROM ips WHERE id = @MaxID;
```

## OPTION #2

Add the address to the PRIMARY KEY to make it a covering index

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ips` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`address`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ips_address_unique` (`address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then, the retrieval can be done like this:

```
SELECT address FROM ips ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

## OPTION #3

Change the Storage Engine to MyISAM

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ips` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`address`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ips_address_unique` (`address`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Since MyISAM requires a full table lock for INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs , this makes the table have the same mechanical behavior as a sequence.

## CAVEAT

You periodically need to clean up the `ips` table

You could just truncate the table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE ips;
```

If you need to keep the distinct list of IPs in the order they were last inserted, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE ips RENAME ips_old;
CREATE TABLE ips_new LIKE ips_old
INSERT INTO ips_new (id,address)
SELECT MAX(id),address FROM ips_old GROUP BY address;
OPTIMIZE TABLE ips_new;
DROP TABLE ips_old;
ALTER TABLE ips_new RENAME ips;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!