# Last row from a query without Order by

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have something like

```
SELECT var1,var2 FROM table where var3=X AND var4=Y order by var5 desc limit 1;
```

Running this query takes roughly 5 seconds on my database which is far to slow.
I was wondering if there was any way to retrieve the last row in a way similar to this

```
SELECT var1,var2 FROM table where var3=X AND var4=Y limit 1;
```

bcause that is almost instant (.03 seconds) on my database. So, if there was some way to have a query print everything in reverse order that would solve every issue I am having. I have been searching for a long while now and every answer seems to be with using `ORDER BY` or subqueries which are all >= 5 seconds.

EDIT The tables are not indexed.

Comment: The concept of "first" or "last" is meaningless without an `order by`.

Comment: Lets say I have row 1, row 2,row 3. How is row 3 being the last meaningless?

Comment: Why is row 3 last? Because it happens to be stored last? What happens if someone reorganizes the table so that it is stored first? Never rely on physical ordering of records for the meaning of your data!

Comment: So this is relevant to my question which I asked? There is always a list of rows it does not matter if the last one is truly the last added row. You are creating an irrelevant argument off the topic of the question.

Comment: @tf3193 No, he isn't. SQL tables do not have any inherent order. Your previous comment *"Lets say I have row 1, row 2,row 3"* is not valid in SQL tables. (Unless you have a specific column, say `rowID` that has these (1,2,3) values stored. If you meant "last as ordered by `val5`", that's fine. But it wasn't obvious in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the table is called `mydb.mytable`

This query

```
SELECT VAR1,VAR2 FROM mydb.mytable where var3=X AND var4=Y order by var5 desc limit 1;
```

can dramatically be improved if you index the table.

There is one of two techniques you can try when indexing the table

## Technique #1

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD INDEX search_index (var3,var4,var5);
```

Within the index, all `var5` values are ordered for every `var3,var4` tuple. It would simply be a rightmost traversal down the BTREE to get to the last `var5`. Then, the row is looked up to retrieve `var1,var2` from the table.

## Technique #2

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD INDEX search_index (var3,var4,var5,var1,var2);
```

This has the same searchability as `INDEX #1`, but with an added bonus: `var1,var2` are already in the index, so there is no need to go back to the table for a separate retrieval. Making an index that has every column requested in a query is called a covering index.

I have discussed [**covering indexes**](http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html) before

- `Jun 12, 2014` : [How to return last used record?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68149/how-to-return-last-used-record/68169#68169)
- `Aug 06, 2013` : [In MySQL if column X has unique values what's the difference between UNIQUE index and B-Tree index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47660/in-mysql-if-column-x-has-unique-values-whats-the-difference-between-unique-inde/47675#47675)
- `Oct 28, 2011` : [Using FORCE INDEX](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7357/using-force-index/7365#7365)
- `Aug 15, 2011` : [How do you increase MySQL performance using current server resources?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/how-do-you-increase-mysql-performance-using-current-server-resources/4650#4650)

## Give it a Try !!!